# Check .NET 4 Full Framework is installed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-client-profile

If the .NET 4 Framework is not installed, the application bring a message, but if only the client framework is installed and the application need the Full Framework, nothing happened and the application starts.

Is there a way to check if .NET 4 Full Framework is installed on the target system and not only the Client Framework?

I search a solution to check it with the "app.manifest" file or in C# on program start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to check if it exists is to follow the advice of the authors and check for the existence of the appropriate registry entry.

The details for each of the keys, including .Net 4, can be found at this reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785

Answer (score 2):

Go to your **Project Properties** screen (Main menu Project/Properites) and then select the **Publish** tab.
Click on the "**Prerequisites**" button you'll note in the list that the check box for "**Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)**" is already checked.

Tick the checkbox for "**Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)**" above it.

Then republish your projeect.

On installation it should now check for the full framework and install it if not present.